# android audio manager in receiver class

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-audiomanager

Not switching back to the mode what user have used.
I mean when phone is in silent and i used to ring for some selected numbers but it does not
switch back to normal mode when phone state is idle.
here's my piece of code.........

```
if(IncomingNumber.equals(WhitelistedNumbers)){
                                    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                                 System.out.println("Number Matches......!");
                                 System.out.println("WhitelistedNumber(s): "+WhitelistedNumbers);


                                }else{
                                    System.out.println("No Match(s) found.....!");

                                }
```

and to switch back to normal mode i m using........

```
 case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                 am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);

                System.out.println("Set to Default Ringer Mode....!");                  
                break;
```

Thanks in advance if any suggestion to sort the problem........

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the previous ringer mode in a variable, and then restore it from that variable.

```
int previousMode;
if(IncomingNumber.equals(WhitelistedNumbers))
{
    previousMode = am.getRingerMode();
    am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
    ....
}
```

and to restore:

```
am.setRingerMode(previousMode);
```

Comment: not working as my TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: method is called before going to its "idle state", Means at the time when phone is in ringing State" so "previous saved mode" does not work as if, Ones it is silent than remains silent after call ends also .....................what to do?????????? @Merlevede